# TYPO3 Error: Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment?

Tags: php, typo3, content-management-system

I have a problem with my TYPO3 Website. Yesterday the Website works with no problems but today I have this Error:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment' not found | Error thrown in file /mnt/web524/e2/72/510353872/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/typo3conf/ext/ws_scss/Classes/Hooks/RenderPreProcessorHook.php in line 76. Requested URL: http://flughaefen.eu/index.php?id=1
```

Can someone help me ?

```php
RenderPreProcessorHook.php in line 76 
 $sitePath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment::getPublicPath() . '/';
```

Comment: Hi @TamilTHL can you show us the part of the code that causes this issue?

Comment: you mean the line 76 ?  $sitePath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment::getPublicPath() . '/';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Environment class was added in TYPO3 9. I see you're using TYPO3 8.7. So the error is correct. You probably updated the extension ws_scss. It looks like version 1.1.14 was the last version that was compatible with TYPO3 8.7, so downgrading to that version should fix the problem (or updating to TYPO3 9.5 or 10.4).

See more version history and compatibility for ws_scss here: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/ws_scss/